# Datatable displaying 2 different entity tables with relation need to get the another column values from database table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, primefaces, dao

i need to get the column values of Language Name from LangDef entity class within single dataTable from UI jsf..please let me ASAP

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" emptyMessage="#{res.NO_RECORDS_FOUND}" var="lab" value="#{labelsMB.listData}" editable="true" editMode="cell" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"   rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"> 
<p:column headerText="#{res.CAPTION_DET}" sortBy="#{lab.captionDet}" filterBy="#{lab.captionDet}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 360px;">
                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{lab.captionDet}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <h:inputText value="#{lab.captionDet}" style="width:96%"/>
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="#{res.LABEL_NO}" sortBy="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.labelNo}" filterBy="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.labelNo}">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.labelNo}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="#{res.LANGUAGE_NO}" sortBy="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.langNo}" filterBy="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.langNo}" width="100">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.langNo}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="#{res.LANGUAGE_NAME}" sortBy="#{lab.???????}" filterBy="#{lab.?????}" width="130">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lab...?????}" />
                                    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

**IAS_LABELS DAO entity :**

```
public interface ILabelsDAO extends CrudRepository<IasLabels, IasLabelsPK>{        
    @Query List<IasLabels> findAll(); 
}
```

**LabelService service class**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LabelService {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LabelService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ILabelsDAO labelRepo;

    public ILabelsDAO getLabelRepo() {
        return labelRepo;
    }

    public void setLabelRepo(ILabelsDAO labelRepo) {
        this.labelRepo = labelRepo;
    }

    public List<IasLabels> getAllLabels() {
        if (this.getLabelRepo() != null) 
            return this.getLabelRepo().findAll();
        return null;
    }

    public Iterable<IasLabels> saveData(List<IasLabels> originalValue) {
        return labelRepo.save(originalValue);
    }

}
```

**LabelsMB ManagedBean implementation**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LabelsMB {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LabelsMB.class);

    List<IasLabels> labelsList = null;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{labelService}")
    private LabelService labelService;

    public LabelService getLabelService() {
         return labelService;
    }

    public void setLabelService(LabelService labelService) {
        this.labelService = labelService;
    }


    public List<IasLabels> getListData() {
        if (labelsList == null || labelsList.isEmpty()) {
            if (this.getLabelService() != null) {
                labelsList = this.getLabelService().getAllLabels();
            }
        }
        return labelsList;
}
```

**LangDef entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANG_DEF")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findAll", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByLangNo", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.langNo = :langNo"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByLangName", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.langName = :langName"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByRepExt", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.repExt = :repExt"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByLangDflt", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.langDflt = :langDflt"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByLangDir", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.langDir = :langDir"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByFlgSt", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.flgSt = :flgSt"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "LangDef.findByLangExt", query = "SELECT l FROM LangDef l WHERE l.langExt = :langExt")})
public class LangDef implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "LANG_NO")
    private Short langNo;
    @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "LANG_NAME")
    private String langName;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "REP_EXT")
    private String repExt;
    @Column(name = "LANG_DFLT")
    private Short langDflt;
    @Column(name = "LANG_DIR")
    private Short langDir;
    @Column(name = "FLG_ST")
    private Short flgSt;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "LANG_EXT")
    private String langExt;

    public LangDef() {
    }

    public LangDef(Short langNo) {
     this.langNo = langNo;
    }

    public Short getLangNo() {
        return langNo;
    }

    public void setLangNo(Short langNo) {
       this.langNo = langNo;
    }

    public String getLangName() {
        return langName;
    }

    public void setLangName(String langName) {
        this.langName = langName;
    }
}
```

i need to get the column values of Language Name from LangDef entity class within single dataTable from UI jsf..please let me ASAP

Comment: you need to combine List<IasLabels> with  LangDef  class right?

Comment: yes...in LangDef entity class i need only LANG_NAME column values of DB

Comment: any relation between IasLabels entity with LangDef entity?

Comment: IASLABELS having column name LANG_NO and LANGDEF also having same column name LANG_NO

Comment: IasMsgsPK entity is LANG_NO and LANGDEF entity primerykey is LANG_NO

Comment: can you please share IASLABELS entity code? so i will give you right solution. because i think you did mistake between relationship.

Comment: how to share its too long code..@Entity
@Table(name = "IAS_LABELS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByLangNo", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.iasLabelsPK.langNo = :langNo"),

Comment: i have fixed your problem you just need to change in your code as per my answer. let me know if you need.

Comment: this error am getting running my project...HTTP Status 500 - could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet – rahul 25 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change in your code like following

in xhtml :

```
<p:column headerText="#{res.LANGUAGE_NAME}" sortBy="#{lab.langDef.langName}"    filterBy="#{lab.langDef.langName}" width="130">
              <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.langDef.langName}" />
</p:column>
```

Entity **IasLabels** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAS_LABELS")
public class IasLabels implements Serializable {

    private LangDef langDef;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LANG_NO", nullable = false)
    public LangDef getLangDef() {
        return this.langDef;
    }

    public void setLangDef(LangDef langDef) {
        this.langDef = langDef;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help to you..

**edited :**

you need to add following in your spring configuration file

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(openSessionInViewInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor(){
        OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
        openSessionInterceptor.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return openSessionInterceptor;
}
```

Comment: this error am getting running my project...HTTP Status 500 - could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: you need remove  fetch = FetchType.LAZY from code and try it

Comment: after doing...got same exception  could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: i think you forget to write this line in your configuration please see my edit answer

Comment: because its working for me and i got result in single table

Comment: watever u said i have added as per ur code but am getting same problem

Comment: can you please send your full error stack on r.kavaiya@gmail.com?

Comment: fwded...please cheack ty so much

Comment: you have alternate option, 
1) create one new class and put both entity object and create getter setter 2) bind with your service class with result with sql result 
3) after bind with new class with arraylist 
4) Now you can retrieve new class with both object in xhtml file

Comment: new Entity class...u mean normal java class with getter and setter method for required field values...?

Comment: normal java class now you need to return new list with new class and bind logic with new class