# one to one mapping Entity class from dataBase using netbeans jpa

Tags: jsf, datatable, hibernate-mapping

jsf single dataTable. I want to get the values from database table column from different entity class. One entity class is IASLABELS  primary key is LANG_NO and LABELS_NO and another entity class is LANGDEF primary key is LANG_NO.

I need LANG_NAME in jsf dataTable column.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IAS_LABELS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByLangNo", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.iasLabelsPK.langNo = :langNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByLabelNo", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.iasLabelsPK.labelNo = :labelNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByCaptionDet", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.captionDet = :captionDet"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByTrnsFlg", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.trnsFlg = :trnsFlg")})
public class IasLabels implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
//    private LangDef langDef;
//
//    public LangDef getLangDef() {
//        return langDef;
//    }
//
//    public void setLangDef(LangDef langDef) {
//        this.langDef = langDef;
//    }
```

Comment: have you know about hibernate one to one mapping?

Comment: I am adding this comment to make it clear for others to answer, he has a composite key in  entity IasLables and a normal primary key in entity LangDef, So he is finding it difficult to do oneToOne mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Answer :** 
You have 1st option with hibernate entity add foreign key primary key as per you database table and used my answer as gave yesterday

[Datatable displaying 2 different entity tables with relation need to get the another column values from database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146088/datatable-displaying-2-different-entity-tables-with-relation-need-to-get-the-ano/36148020#36148020)

**2) Answer**

Now you have Alternate option 
1) you need to create normal class like following

```
public class IasLabelsWithLang implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private IasLabels  lasLabels;
    private LangDef langDef;


    public LangDef getLangDef() {
        return langDef;
    }

    public void setLangDef(LangDef langDef) {
        this.langDef = langDef;
    }

    public IasLabels getIasLabels() {
        return iasLabels;
    }

    public void setIasLabels(IasLabels iasLabels) {
        this.iasLabels = iasLabels;
    }   
}
```

2) you need to change following thing in your manage bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LabelsMB {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LabelsMB.class);

    List<IasLabelsWithLang> labelsList = null;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{labelService}")
    private LabelService labelService;

    public LabelService getLabelService() {
         return labelService;
    }

    public void setLabelService(LabelService labelService) {
        this.labelService = labelService;
    }

    public List<IasLabelsWithLang> getListData() {
        if (labelsList == null || labelsList.isEmpty()) {
            if (this.getLabelService() != null) {
                labelsList = this.getLabelService().getAllLabels();
            }
        }
        return labelsList;
    }
}
```

3) You need to following changes in your services class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LabelService {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LabelService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ILabelsDAO labelRepo;

    @Autowired
    private LangDefDAO langDefDAO;


    public ILabelsDAO getLabelRepo() {
        return labelRepo;
    }

    public void setLabelRepo(ILabelsDAO labelRepo) {
        this.labelRepo = labelRepo;
    }

    public List<IasLabelsWithLang> getAllLabels() {
        List<IasLabelsWithLang> list = new ArrayList<IasLabelsWithLang>();
        if (this.getLabelRepo() != null) {
            List<IasLabels> lasLabelsList = this.getLabelRepo().findAll();
            for(IasLabels lasLabels : lasLabelsList){
                IasLabelsWithLang  model = new IasLabelsWithLang();
                model.setIasLabels(lasLabels);
                model.setLangDef(langDefDAO.findByPk(lasLabels.getLangNo()));

                list.add(model);
            }
            return list;
        }            
        return null;
    }

    public Iterable<IasLabels> saveData(List<IasLabels> originalValue) {
        return labelRepo.save(originalValue);
    }
}
```

4) You need to do in your XHTML file for flowing changes

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" emptyMessage="#{res.NO_RECORDS_FOUND}" var="lab" value="#{labelsMB.listData}" editable="true" editMode="cell" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorTemplate="  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"   rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"> 
<p:column headerText="#{res.CAPTION_DET}" sortBy="#{lab.lasLabels.captionDet}" filterBy="#{lab.lasLabels.captionDet}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 360px;">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{lab.lasLabels.captionDet}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{lab.lasLabels.captionDet}" style="width:96%"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{res.LABEL_NO}" sortBy="#{lab.lasLabels.iasLabelsPK.labelNo}" filterBy="#{lab.lasLabels.iasLabelsPK.labelNo}">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.labelNo}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{res.LANGUAGE_NO}" sortBy="#{lab.lasLabels.iasLabelsPK.langNo}" filterBy="#{lab.lasLabels.iasLabelsPK.langNo}" width="100">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.iasLabelsPK.langNo}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{res.LANGUAGE_NAME}" sortBy="#{lab.langDef.langName}" filterBy="#{lab.langDef.langName}" width="130">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{lab.langDef.langName}" />
    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Hope, you would be fix problem.. :)

**EDITED** 
You need to add **langNo** variable inside your **IasLabels**  entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IAS_LABELS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByLangNo", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.iasLabelsPK.langNo = :langNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByLabelNo", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.iasLabelsPK.labelNo = :labelNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByCaptionDet", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.captionDet = :captionDet"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "IasLabels.findByTrnsFlg", query = "SELECT i FROM IasLabels i WHERE i.trnsFlg = :trnsFlg")})
public class IasLabels implements Serializable {

    // langNo variable you need to add in your IasLabels entity
    @Column(name = "LANG_NO")
    private Short langNo;

    public Short getLangNo() {
        return langNo;
    }

    public void setLangNo(Short langNo) {
        this.langNo = langNo;
    }

}
```

Comment: model.setLangDef(langDefDAO.findByPk(lasLabels.getLangNo()));....am getting error here getLangNo()

Comment: findByPk this your function name which one field pk data from entity as per in your DAO class method, it just a example 

* lasLabels.getLangNo() its langNo object from your lasLabels entity

Comment: langDefDAO.findBYID() with Lang_No short  parameter right?

Comment: LANG_NO 1 1 1 N NUMBER (2)  None 4 0 0.25    False

Comment: langDefDAO.findBYID(LANG_NO) so you get entity object of particulate primary key

Comment: see my edited answer :

**EDITED You need to add langNo variable inside your IasLabels entity**

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.xyz.onxLabels.entity.IasLabels column: LANG_NO (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: @ Ravi Kavaiya...ty i got the result